# How to replace a string in Woocommerce single product variation description?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

Could someone please advise how I go about doing a PHP string replace via action or filter (or manipulating the markup) of the single product variation description in WooCommerce?

There doesn't appear to be any hooks for this.

The above is so that I can turn each line break of the description into a list item.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use Wordpress dedicated [**`gettex`**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/gettext) hook in a custom hooked function, this way:

```
add_filter('gettext', 'wc_custom_renaming', 10, 3);
function wc_custom_renaming( $replaced_text, $source_text, $domain ) {
    // only for single product pages
    if( is_product() ) {
        // Set here the complete description to be replaced
        if( $source_text == 'The text to replace' ){
            // Set here your replacement description
            $replaced_text = __( 'Your new text',$domain );
        }
    }
    return $replaced_text;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

> This will work only if you replace the complete description. If you wish to replace only a word or a substring, you will need to customize this function further with **`strpos()`** and **`str_replace()`** php functions for example...

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of this filter. I need this to specifically target description for a product variant, and to string replace ' - ' with '<li>'.

Could you please advise how I'd modify your original suggestion to accommodate this?